# Truly Refresh/Reload a jQuery mobile page div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm currently working with a file that contains several jQM page divs (single page approach).
I have a refresh button in the header of these pages that I'm trying to get to refresh individual page divs based on "getActivePage". The reason for this interactivity is there is a running list of items that users will be needing to refresh to see new content coming in to listview(s).

I've had various visual refreshes altering the following function, but none seem to totally refresh the DOM or the contents of a desired pagecontainer or jQM page div. With the following code, I'm able to see a visual transition and I arrive at the desired/same jQM page div that I'm trying to refresh. The problem is, the contents aren't really being reloaded it seems. (I have a way in the test environment of changing the listviews to test the refreshes and I'm not seeing those changes take effect) I'm wondering if I'm not passing in "id_urlNav" properly or if this is even possible with .pagecontainer("change"...).

When all was lost, I ended up inserting window.location.reload();, but this seems to be bad form for pagecontainer manipulation. If anyone has any idea why this isn't working, please let me know. Thanks in advance for reviewing!

```
// script to reload/refresh jQM pages
// scoped to internal page hashes vs. overall window
// "change" is used vs. "load" for internal reloads vs. AJAX content
function refreshPages() {
// the camel casing on the first part of the pageContainer object below
// is important
var id_url = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")[0].id;
var id_urlNav = "#" + id_url;
console.log("id_urlNav" + " =" + " " + id_urlNav );
// window.location.reload();

// keeping the below in case 1.5 finally arives with proven solution
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( "change", id_urlNav, 
  {
    allowSamePageTransition : true,
    showLoadMsg             : true,
    // reloadPage reloads entire jQM set of pages, forgetting the getActivePage
    // reloadPage is deprecated
    // reload "reloads" the getActivePage, but doesn't show new content
    reload                  : true,
    transition              : 'fade', 
    changeHash              : 'true'
    } 
);
}
// /refresh code
```

I read some on the jQuery forums about there being a bug related to reload: vs. the now deprecated reloadPage:, but I don't know if that is some of the cause of the malfunction or not.

Comment: Your code shows the page refresh but not where the new data is coming from...Instead of refreshing the whole page, why not make and ajax call and repopulate the list from the ajax results?

Comment: `reloadPage` is deprecated, yet it works. There is a bug in `reload` that isn't fixed yet https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7406

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions folks. Yeah, It sounds like I need to figure out how to inject this content via AJAX vs. having everything loaded once in the DOM. I'm assuming that the above function using "change" will automatically allow these pagecontainer(s) to show the newly updated content? Is that why it isn't necessarily a "true" refresh in the function above? I guess this is jQM's way of refreshing the overall container and AJAX is doing the rest. Sorry if this is a dumb supplement to the question, it's just that none of it is apparent when researching the jQM 1.4.3 documentation.

Comment: Note that `reload` or `reloadPage` work only with URL not with #page fragment. As @ezanker said, you can load contents via Ajax instead of reloading whole document.

Comment: Again, I appreciate everyone's feedback. We didn't have the infrastructure in-house to inject the content from a certain platform, so I went with a location.reload() supplemented by a call to the loader widget, which spins and gives better feedback on mobile devices than relying on mobile Safari's subtle cues that something's going on. Check out these examples => http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/loader/